# Appium - AndroidDriver shutdowns before end of test

Tags: android, ubuntu, appium, robotframework, selenium-grid

I am making a test using appium and robot framework which aims to check the internet connection of the device. We are using a specific app (Speedtest) to do this.
So the test in itself seems to be working well but during the actual connection test within the app (usually at the end of the upstream test), the appium node receives a DELETE request, which ends up terminating the session before the test could end and I don't know why. My guess is that I might have to "keepalive" the session or something, but  I don't know how to do that.

I am also using Selenium grid if that changes anything.

Here is the robotframework code, which is rather simple:

```
Play Speedtest
    [Arguments]    ${udid}
    Open Application    ${appium_url}    platformName=Android    deviceName=Android 4.2    appPackage=org.zwanoo.android.speedtest    appActivity=com.ookla.speedtest.softfacade.MainActivity    udid=${udid}
    Sleep    10s
    TAp    xpath=//android.widget.TextView[@text="Commencez le test"]
    Log    "Test en cours"
    Sleep    40s
    Capture Page Screenshot
    Page should contain element    xpath=//android.widget.TextView[@resource-id="org.zwanoo.android.speedtest:id/o2_button_text"]
    Close Application
```

Here are the log lines on the appium server side (it's a dev platform so everything on the same computer):

```
2016-06-16 13:59:32:146 - [HTTP] --> DELETE /wd/hub/session/bf41fb4b-0323-41fa-a256-b697af1ece43 
2016-06-16 13:59:32:147 - [MJSONWP] Calling AppiumDriver.deleteSession() with args: ["bf41fb4b-0323-41fa-a256-b697af1ece43"]
2016-06-16 13:59:32:148 - [debug] [AndroidDriver] Shutting down Android driver
2016-06-16 13:59:32:149 - [debug] [ADB] Getting connected devices...
2016-06-16 13:59:32:157 - [debug] [ADB] 1 device(s) connected
2016-06-16 13:59:32:160 - [debug] [ADB] Running /home/lisnet/mobile_test/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools/adb with args: ["-P",5037,"-s","1ba5109c","shell","am","force-stop","org.zwanoo.android.speedtest"]
2016-06-16 13:59:32:790 - [debug] [ADB] Pressing the HOME button
2016-06-16 13:59:32:791 - [debug] [ADB] Getting connected devices...
2016-06-16 13:59:32:803 - [debug] [ADB] 1 device(s) connected
2016-06-16 13:59:32:804 - [debug] [ADB] Running /home/lisnet/mobile_test/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools/adb with args: ["-P",5037,"-s","1ba5109c","shell","input","keyevent",3]
2016-06-16 13:59:33:308 - [debug] [Logcat] Stopping logcat capture
2016-06-16 13:59:33:311 - [debug] [AndroidBootstrap] Sending command to android: {"cmd":"shutdown"}
2016-06-16 13:59:33:318 - [AndroidBootstrap] [BOOTSTRAP LOG] [debug] Got data from client: {"cmd":"shutdown"}
2016-06-16 13:59:33:319 - [AndroidBootstrap] [BOOTSTRAP LOG] [debug] Got command of type SHUTDOWN
2016-06-16 13:59:33:319 - [AndroidBootstrap] [BOOTSTRAP LOG] [debug] Returning result: {"status":0,"value":"OK, shutting down"}
2016-06-16 13:59:33:320 - [AndroidBootstrap] [BOOTSTRAP LOG] [debug] Closed client connection
2016-06-16 13:59:33:320 - [debug] [AndroidBootstrap] [UIAUTO STDOUT] INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS: numtests=1
2016-06-16 13:59:33:321 - [debug] [AndroidBootstrap] [UIAUTO STDOUT] INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS: stream=.
2016-06-16 13:59:33:321 - [debug] [AndroidBootstrap] [UIAUTO STDOUT] INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS: id=UiAutomatorTestRunner
2016-06-16 13:59:33:322 - [debug] [AndroidBootstrap] [UIAUTO STDOUT] INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS: test=testRunServer
2016-06-16 13:59:33:322 - [debug] [AndroidBootstrap] [UIAUTO STDOUT] INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS: class=io.appium.android.bootstrap.Bootstrap
2016-06-16 13:59:33:323 - [debug] [AndroidBootstrap] [UIAUTO STDOUT] INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS: current=1
2016-06-16 13:59:33:323 - [debug] [AndroidBootstrap] [UIAUTO STDOUT] INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS_CODE: 0
2016-06-16 13:59:33:324 - [debug] [AndroidBootstrap] [UIAUTO STDOUT] INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS: stream=
2016-06-16 13:59:33:325 - [debug] [AndroidBootstrap] [UIAUTO STDOUT] Test results for WatcherResultPrinter=.
2016-06-16 13:59:33:325 - [debug] [AndroidBootstrap] [UIAUTO STDOUT] Time: 64.127
2016-06-16 13:59:33:326 - [debug] [AndroidBootstrap] [UIAUTO STDOUT] OK (1 test)
2016-06-16 13:59:33:326 - [debug] [AndroidBootstrap] [UIAUTO STDOUT] INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS_CODE: -1
2016-06-16 13:59:33:327 - [debug] [AndroidBootstrap] Received command result from bootstrap
2016-06-16 13:59:33:328 - [debug] [UiAutomator] Shutting down UiAutomator
2016-06-16 13:59:33:329 - [debug] [UiAutomator] Moving to state 'stopping'
2016-06-16 13:59:33:330 - [debug] [UiAutomator] UiAutomator shut down normally
2016-06-16 13:59:33:330 - [debug] [UiAutomator] Moving to state 'stopped'
2016-06-16 13:59:33:331 - [debug] [ADB] Attempting to kill all uiautomator processes
2016-06-16 13:59:33:331 - [debug] [ADB] Getting all processes with uiautomator
2016-06-16 13:59:33:332 - [debug] [ADB] Getting connected devices...
2016-06-16 13:59:33:339 - [debug] [ADB] 1 device(s) connected
2016-06-16 13:59:33:341 - [debug] [ADB] Running /home/lisnet/mobile_test/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools/adb with args: ["-P",5037,"-s","1ba5109c","shell","ps","uiautomator"]
2016-06-16 13:59:33:489 - [ADB] No uiautomator process found to kill, continuing...
2016-06-16 13:59:33:489 - [debug] [UiAutomator] Moving to state 'stopped'
2016-06-16 13:59:33:490 - [Appium] Removing session bf41fb4b-0323-41fa-a256-b697af1ece43 from our master session list
2016-06-16 13:59:33:491 - [debug] [MJSONWP] Received response: null
2016-06-16 13:59:33:491 - [debug] [MJSONWP] But deleting session, so not returning
2016-06-16 13:59:33:491 - [MJSONWP] Responding to client with driver.deleteSession() result: null
2016-06-16 13:59:33:492 - [HTTP] <-- DELETE /wd/hub/session/bf41fb4b-0323-41fa-a256-b697af1ece43 200 1346 ms - 76
```

Thank you for your time & help.

Vincent

Comment: how did you solve it ? i'm facing the same !

Comment: Hello Emma, we ended up writing everything in Python instead and using another app (iPerf).

Comment: i'm using java here my error it's a bit similar !  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41976782/application-crash-at-the-moment-i-run-my-testng-while-using-appium

Comment: Est ce que vous avez des solutions à me proposer pour mon cas?