# Application crash at the moment i run my testNG while using Appium

Tags: android, automation, appium

I have a problem every thing is right configured here my code :

```
import io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver;
import io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidElement;

import java.io.File;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.testng.annotations.AfterClass;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeClass;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;

public class Newlook_1 {

    AndroidDriver<AndroidElement> driver;

    File path = new File(
            "/home/emna/Téléchargements/AutomationFiles/app-debug.apk");

    @BeforeClass
    public void setUp() throws MalformedURLException {

        System.out.println("app Dir.--->" + path);

        DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
        capabilities.setCapability("deviceName", "SM-G531H");
        capabilities.setCapability("version", "5.1.1");
        capabilities.setCapability("platformName", "Android");
        capabilities.setCapability("device", "Android");
        capabilities.setCapability("platformVersion", "platform");
        capabilities.setCapability("udid", "***********");
        capabilities.setCapability("app", path.getAbsolutePath());
        capabilities.setCapability("appPackage", "com.bulldozer.newlook");
        capabilities.setCapability("appActivity", "com.bulldozer.newlook.activities.SplashActivity");
        capabilities.setCapability("noReset", "false");
        driver = new AndroidDriver<AndroidElement>(new URL(
                "http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), capabilities);
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(1500, TimeUnit.SECONDS);


    }

    @Test
    public void Test1() throws InterruptedException {

        driver.wait(10000);
        System.out.println("newlook-tutoriel");
        driver.findElement(By.id("skip")).click();
        System.out.println("newlook-welcome");
        driver.wait(1000);
        driver.findElement(By.id("btn_signin_welcome")).click();
        System.out.println("newlook-Me connecter");
        driver.findElement(By.id("input_email")).sendKeys("e@e.emmna.com");
        driver.findElement(By.id("input_password")).sendKeys("00000000");
    }

    @AfterClass
    public void tearDown() {
        driver.quit();

    }

}
```

while i run appium with npm using :

```
appium -a 127.0.0.1
```

It looks like the application start after a while it get crashed !

Here my appium log file it tells that there is a IllegalMonitorStateException in java add to that :

```
[debug] [ADB] Running '/home/emna/Android/Sdk/platform-tools/adb' with args: ["-P",5037,"-s","********","shell","am","force-stop","com.bulldozer.newlook"]
[debug] [ADB] Pressing the HOME button
[debug] [ADB] Getting connected devices...
[debug] [ADB] 1 device(s) connected
[debug] [ADB] Running '/home/emna/Android/Sdk/platform-tools/adb' with args: ["-P",5037,"-s","************","shell","input","keyevent",3]
[debug] [AndroidBootstrap] Sending command to android: {"cmd":"shutdown"}
[AndroidBootstrap] [BOOTSTRAP LOG] [debug] Got data from client: {"cmd":"shutdown"}
[AndroidBootstrap] [BOOTSTRAP LOG] [debug] Got command of type SHUTDOWN
[AndroidBootstrap] [BOOTSTRAP LOG] [debug] Returning result: {"status":0,"value":"OK, shutting down"}
[AndroidBootstrap] [BOOTSTRAP LOG] [debug] Closed client connection
[debug] [AndroidBootstrap] [UIAUTO STDOUT] INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS: numtests=1
[debug] [AndroidBootstrap] [UIAUTO STDOUT] INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS: stream=.
[debug] [AndroidBootstrap] [UIAUTO STDOUT] INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS: id=UiAutomatorTestRunner
[debug] [AndroidBootstrap] [UIAUTO STDOUT] INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS: test=testRunServer
[debug] [AndroidBootstrap] [UIAUTO STDOUT] INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS: class=io.appium.android.bootstrap.Bootstrap
[debug] [AndroidBootstrap] [UIAUTO STDOUT] INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS: current=1
[debug] [AndroidBootstrap] [UIAUTO STDOUT] INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS_CODE: 0
[debug] [AndroidBootstrap] [UIAUTO STDOUT] INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS: stream=
[debug] [AndroidBootstrap] [UIAUTO STDOUT] Test results for WatcherResultPrinter=.
[debug] [AndroidBootstrap] [UIAUTO STDOUT] Time: 12.803
[debug] [AndroidBootstrap] [UIAUTO STDOUT] OK (1 test)
[debug] [AndroidBootstrap] [UIAUTO STDOUT] INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS_CODE: -1
[debug] [AndroidBootstrap] Received command result from bootstrap
[debug] [UiAutomator] Shutting down UiAutomator
[debug] [UiAutomator] Moving to state 'stopping'
[debug] [UiAutomator] UiAutomator shut down normally
[debug] [UiAutomator] Moving to state 'stopped'
[debug] [ADB] Attempting to kill all uiautomator processes
[debug] [ADB] Getting all processes with uiautomator
[debug] [ADB] Getting connected devices...
[debug] [ADB] 1 device(s) connected
[debug] [ADB] Running '/home/emna/Android/Sdk/platform-tools/adb' with args: ["-P",5037,"-s","******","shell","ps"]
[ADB] No uiautomator process found to kill, continuing...
[debug] [UiAutomator] Moving to state 'stopped'
[debug] [ADB] Getting connected devices...
[debug] [ADB] 1 device(s) connected
[debug] [ADB] Running '/home/emna/Android/Sdk/platform-tools/adb' with args: ["-P",5037,"-s","4b13731fdfdd824e","shell","am","force-stop","io.appium.unlock"]
[debug] [Logcat] Stopping logcat capture
[debug] [AndroidDriver] Not cleaning generated files. Add `clearSystemFiles` capability if wanted.
[Appium] Removing session 7fe5b58a-8d00-4f8a-9aa8-f61f2d374eb6 from our master session list
[debug] [MJSONWP] Received response: null
[debug] [MJSONWP] But deleting session, so not returning
[debug] [MJSONWP] Responding to client with driver.deleteSession() result: null
[HTTP] <-- DELETE /wd/hub/session/7fe5b58a-8d00-4f8a-9aa8-f61f2d374eb6 200 2319 ms - 76
```

How can i solve this problem? shall i restart the remote session ? 
Thanks in advance for any solution you propose :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve it just by removing : `driver.wait(10000);`

Answer (score 1):

I am facing the same problem. However, it doesn't happen with all the devices.

The workaround which I am using :

1. Close all instances of UIAutomator before you start the execution.
2. Start appium server through AppiumDriverLocalService (not manually);
3. Increase the timeout of new command (We need to specify in the DesiredCapabilities).

You can try this

Comment: i have removed driver.wait(10000); all is fine ! thanks any way

Comment: @Emna Why do you use wait(10000)? You can use flexiWait and no need to wait for 10000 every time. If it is the specific requirement then fine.

Comment: because splash screen takes too much time, but it's fine now even if i remove all of them. At the beginning i add them because of splash screen

Comment: @Emna Can I suggest you one more thing?

Comment: @Emna As I can see in your code that you are using "app" capability in which you mentioned the path of the apk file. If you mention this, appium will copy the file to device and install for everytime you instantiate appium driver. This usually takes around 30 seconds to 1 minute depends on the apk size. You can avoid this by installing the app on the device only one time and removing the "app" capability.

Comment: thanks a lot @vinod for your nice suggestion in fact i have an old issue that takes many days and finally the problem were from the apk file itself and not from my code, at the period i saw many solution one of them to add the app capabilities ;) i will remove it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41812593/unable-to-create-new-remote-session-desired-capabilities-capabilities

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134582/discussion-between-vinod-and-emna).